# Asset validation Error while validating app in Xcode (Missing info.plist value etc.)

Tags: ios, xcode, assets, info.plist

In the process of validating the Flutter app through xcode, an asset validation error occurred repeatedly, so I would like to ask for advice on this.

"Asset validation failed
Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.arsvivendi.trainer4u'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7. (ID: 9926d574-67a6-4ae0-a83e-bb78686faf4d)

Asset validation failed
Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. To support older versions of iOS, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface (ID: 0011cc30-99a2-4b72-96d1-b8cc5f1f4cb3)

Asset validation failed
Storyboard file 'Main~iphone.storyboardc' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename. (ID: b4dc8713-6349-4b39-ad21-d51e1aea4bb3)

Asset validation failed
Storyboard file 'Main~ipad.storyboardc' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename. (ID: 13094918-0f38-4ab4-add8-6c2b582042b4)"